# User added\deleted event in sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

How can i know when a user is added (or deleted) to a sharepoint site or to a group in a sharepoint site?
I tried to attach an SPItemEventReceiver on the user information list, but the main problem  is that i can't know when a user is added (removed) from a group...

What is the best approach to do that?? noting that i'm using it for licensing purpose and i want to know when the number of users in a specific group passed the maximum of the allowed number.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unexpected pain to implement: Refer to this previous [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295993/how-to-get-notified-about-changes-on-sharepoint-groups) or Aaron Han's answer in [this social thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/fb7375ec-eee1-457b-9a3e-4cacec2ebd55).